# Non left-aligned equations

Tags: horizontal-alignment

My equation is not left-aligned; see the attached image. I'd like it to be left-aligned.

```
\begin{equation} P(w_{i} | h) =   \left\{
      \begin{aligned}
        \frac{n(h, w_{i})}{n(h)}    Si n(h, w_{i}) > k\\
        d_{r} \frac{n(h, w_{i})}{n(h)}\\
        \alpha(h) P(w_{i} | h^{-1}\\
      \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: The first column in an alignment is right aligned. You might want to have a look at the cases env, faster to use as the { is build in

Answer (score 3):

While you can use an `aligned` environment, your use is better-suited for the `cases` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Sin}{Sin}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  P(w_i \mid h) = \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{n(h, w_i)}{n(h)} \Sin(h, w_i) > k \\
    d_r \dfrac{n(h, w_{i})}{n(h)} \\
    \alpha(h) P(w_i \mid h^{-1})
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `aligned`, you have to add an ampersand `&`:

```
\begin{equation} P(w_{i} | h) = \left{
  \begin{aligned}
    & \frac{n(h, w_{i})}{n(h)}    Si n(h, w_{i}) > k\\
    & d_{r} \frac{n(h, w_{i})}{n(h)}\\
    & \alpha(h) P(w_{i} | h^{-1}\\
  \end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

The formula in each row of the `aligned` environment can be structured by putting `&` at the right places.  The idea is that corresponding `&`s of different rows will be aligned on top of each other.  In order to align arbitrary formulas at specific points, the parts before the first `&` is right aligned, the part after the second `&` is left aligned, and then it alternates.